# Why does adding FROM clause resolve the effect of WHERE condition in subquery on main query?

Tags: t-sql, subquery

In my research, I want to see diseases correlated to diabetes by listing all diseases which co-occurs with diabetes, i.e. when there is at least one patient who has medical record of both diabetes and that disease. At first I try this query:

```
use [ng_data]
select distinct [disease]
from [dbo].[Final_View_2]
where [encode_id] in
(
    select [encode_id] 
    where [disease] like '%diabetes%'
)
```

Where `encode_id` is the id of patient. But this query only returns diseases whose name contain 'diabetes'. It looks like the condition in subquery affects results in main query.

Then when I try this query:

```
use [ng_data]
select distinct [disease]
from [dbo].[Final_View_2]
where [encode_id] in
(
    select [encode_id]
    from [dbo].[Final_View_2]
    where [disease] like '%diabetes%'
)
```

it works correctly. It seems that adding `from` clause in the subquery can resolve the effect of `where` clause in subquery on the main query. Could someone explain how the queries are carried out and why it produces such result? I'm confused by the dependence of main query on subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query is acting like a correlated sub-query, i.e. the rows it is referencing come from the result set in the outer query. It is in effect just saying "*is the column value in this row like '%diabetes%'*"; it is therefore no different to putting that `WHERE` clause in the outer query.

By add the `FROM` in your sub-query you are creating a secondary resultset of encodeids that have diabetes in the disease column and **then** selecting all rows that have that encodeid in the first resultset without reference to the disease column.

Take a look at the execution plan for each query to see what it is doing